# Missing SiteColumn in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-2013, content-type, site-column

I have a Content Type with a number of Site Columns inside it.

I added this content type to a Document Library, however, one of the site columns is not appearing.

I'm using SharePoint on premise - the site columns and content type should have been properly created as it even works fine for some other document libraries.. I only have the problem, with exactly the same content types, in some document libraries... Can it be fixed without having to re-create document library?

I have tried removing and re-adding the column but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the site column from the content type, deleting the site column, re-creating the site column and readding it to the content type. This solved the issue of the missing field in the list settings of the document library for me. The only issue with this is that the internal name now changed to whatever it was and a 0 in the end, so i will have to update all code and workflow references accordingly.